# How to construct a webob.Request or a WSGI 'environ' dict from raw HTTP request byte stream?

Tags: python, wsgi, webob

Suppose I have a byte stream with the following in it:

```
POST /mum/ble?q=huh
Content-Length: 18
Content-Type: application/json; charset="utf-8"
Host: localhost:80

["do", "re", "mi"]
```

Is there a way to produce an WSGI-style 'environ' dict from it?

Hopefully, I've overlooked an easy answer, and it is as easy to achieve as the opposite operation.
Consider:

```
>>> import json
>>> from webob import Request
>>> r = Request.blank('/mum/ble?q=huh')
>>> r.method = 'POST'
>>> r.content_type = 'application/json'
>>> r.charset = 'utf-8'
>>> r.body = json.dumps(['do', 're', 'mi'])
>>> print str(r) # Request's __str__ method gives raw HTTP bytes back!
```

```
POST /mum/ble?q=huh
Content-Length: 18
Content-Type: application/json; charset="utf-8"
Host: localhost:80

["do", "re", "mi"]
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Reusing Python's standard library code for the purpose is a bit tricky (it was not designed to be reused that way!-), but should be doable, e.g:

```
import cStringIO
from wsgiref import simple_server, util

input_string = """POST /mum/ble?q=huh HTTP/1.0
Content-Length: 18
Content-Type: application/json; charset="utf-8"
Host: localhost:80

["do", "re", "mi"]
"""

class FakeHandler(simple_server.WSGIRequestHandler):
    def __init__(self, rfile):
        self.rfile = rfile
        self.wfile = cStringIO.StringIO() # for error msgs
        self.server = self
        self.base_environ = {}
        self.client_address = ['?', 80]
        self.raw_requestline = self.rfile.readline()
        self.parse_request()

    def getenv(self):
        env = self.get_environ()
        util.setup_testing_defaults(env)
        env['wsgi.input'] = self.rfile
        return env

handler = FakeHandler(rfile=cStringIO.StringIO(input_string))
wsgi_env = handler.getenv()

print wsgi_env
```

Basically, we need to subclass the request handler to fake out the construction process that's normally performed for it by the server (`rfile` and `wfile` built from the socket to the client, and so on). This isn't quite complete, I think, but should be close and I hope it proves helpful!

Note that I've also fixed your example HTTP request: without an `HTTP/1.0` or 1.1 at the end of the raw request line, a `POST` is considered ill-formed and causes an exception and a resulting error message on `handler.wfile`.

Comment: Alex, thanks, it works as advertised. And I also round-tripped that dict again through webob.Request.__str__ and got expected results (minus HTTP version, which Request class does not produce for some reason).

Comment: I suspect that the "self.server = self" leads to a memory leak.  Therefore it'd be a good idea, after doing "handler = FakeHandler(...)", to do "del handler.server".

Comment: @offby1, a reference loop (which `self.server = self` does create) is not a memory leak, as Python does have garbage collection for reference loops; if you can break the loop advisedly, that will minutely speed things up by avoiding the `gc` pass.